# What affects the speed of the following Java code? (Fraudulent Activity Notifications on HackerRank)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, queue

[Problem Statement:](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fraudulent-activity-notifications/problem)

The following code passes the tests for correctness but does not fit the execution time frames.

One of the hints stated that I might want to use Queues and Counting Sort for the following problem. I've learned how to do Counting Sort, but haven't applied it. 
I need to **understand** why has been a Queue recommended to me (I read Java API but I didn't understand what are advantages of the ability to retrieve or delete the first and last element only could give me in this situation) and why is my current code not efficient enough(I made it quite short with just one for-loop)?

Another thing, as stated on the official API webpage, Arrays.sort() use dual-pivot Quicksort. I read that this type of sorting tends to be quicker than the Counting sort, then why is it recommended?

Also, what is O(1) time complexity for.

```
static int activityNotifications(int[] expenditure, int d) {
        int numOfNotif = 0;
        //for each element starting from d up to the pre-last element
        // proceed to next element in the array
        for (int i = d; i < expenditure.length; i++) {
            //add the elements that are needed for calculating the median
            int[] trailingDays = Arrays.copyOfRange(expenditure, i - d, i);
            Arrays.sort(expenditure, i - d, i);
            //calculate the median
            double median;
            int index = (trailingDays.length - 1) / 2;
            if (trailingDays.length % 2 == 0) {
                median = (trailingDays[index] + trailingDays[index + 1]);
                median /= 2;
            } else
                median = trailingDays[index];
            //check if median violates the condition
            if (expenditure[i] >= 2 * median)
                numOfNotif++;
        }
        return numOfNotif;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Java solution **passed all tests**.

```
//What exactly is a median? It is the number that is in the middle
    //of a sorted collection of numbers or the average of two middle numbers
    //if the number of numbers in the collection is odd.
    //When solving this problem we need to save every millisecond.
    //In this solution, the "Running window" technique with
    //PriorityQueues is implemented.
    //The advantage of PriorityQueues is that when you use them
    //there is a guarantee that the lowest/biggest number will be the head of
    //the Queue. Thus, we do not have to spend any time and space on sorting our arrays
    //or copying and sorting a new array each time. We work with our initial array
    //during the whole iteration.
    static int activityNotifications(int[] expenditure, int d) {
        int numOfNotif = 0;
        double median;
        //Create a PriorityQueue that will store the bigger numbers (we will use
        // the minimum value of this Queue).
        PriorityQueue<Integer> max = new PriorityQueue<>();
        //Create a PriorityQueue that will store the smaller numbers (we will use
        // the maximum value of this Queue). Reversing the order will guarantee that we
        //get the biggest number as the head.
        PriorityQueue<Integer> min = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        //As the Queues are currently empty, we need to fill each of them with at least
        //one element - so these will be the first two of the array.
        if (expenditure[0] < expenditure[1]) {
            min.add(expenditure[0]);
            max.add(expenditure[1]);
        } else {
            max.add(expenditure[0]);
            min.add(expenditure[1]);
        }
        //Once we have the first two element we can now implement the "Sliding Window"
        //technique.
        for (int i = 2; i < expenditure.length - 1; i++) {
            //We iterate until expenditure.length - 1 because we always compare the median
            //with the ensuing element.
            //If the current element is smaller than the smallest element of the 
            //Queue with bigger elements, then we'll add it into the smaller elements Queue
            if (expenditure[i] < max.peek())
                min.add(expenditure[i]);
            else
                max.add(expenditure[i]);
            //If the median is the middle element in a sorted collection, we have to make
            //sure that the elements we use for the median identification are 
            //actually in the middle. The only way of ensuring this is to check that 
            //both Queues are almost equal in size or equal. That is why we have to balance
            //them each time we add things into the collection.
            balance(min, max);
            //Once the sum of sizes of both Queues is equal to the window size d 
            //we start calculating the median and checking whether it violates the condition. 
            if (max.size() + min.size() == d) {
                if (min.size() == max.size())
                    median = ((double)min.peek() + (double)max.peek()) /2;
                else if (min.size() > max.size())
                    median = min.peek();
                else
                    median = max.peek();
                if (expenditure[i + 1] >= 2 * median)
                    numOfNotif++;
                //After doing the work, we now have to move the window.
                //So we now remove the first element from the beginning. The window will
                //now be size d-1, but in the next iteration, the new element will be added from 
                //the beginning so it will (d - 1) + 1.
                //Moving the window means keeping it the same size all the way through iteration.

                //Be careful here, the element needs to be removed as if we were removing it from the
                //array, but our array is split in two Queues, so we need to remove it only from one Queue
                if (max.contains(expenditure[i - d + 1]))
                    //i - d would produce a NullPointer Exception because of the confusion with 
                    //normal numbers and indexes, which begin with 0.
                    max.remove(expenditure[i - d + 1]);
                else
                    min.remove(expenditure[i - d + 1]);
            }
        }
        return numOfNotif;
    }

    public static void balance(PriorityQueue<Integer> min, PriorityQueue<Integer> max) {
        if (max.size() - min.size() > 1) {
            min.add(max.peek());
            max.remove(max.peek());
        }
        if (min.size() - max.size() > 1) {
            max.add(min.peek());
            min.remove(min.peek());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking carefully at the definition of [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)

> I made it quite short with just one for-loop.

---

Although it is one for loop, if the array has `n` elements (aka n days), and we need to calculate the days of fraud notifications after the first `d` days, we need to enter the for loop `n-d+1` times.

And each time we enter the for loop, we first copying the subarray of length `d` and then perform a sort on it

copying: `O(d)` in time complexity

sorting (assuming quick sort on the average case): `O(d * log(d))` in time complexity.

So the overall time complexity for this algorithm is `O(n * d * log(d))`, if we neglect the smaller terms.

---

The hints on using queue are for us to look at the problem as a whole and try to find patterns. In this case, it is called a [sliding window pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MK-NZ4hN7rs).

The idea behind `sliding window` is smart: When we process `[20, 30, 40]`, we can leverage the information generated when we were processing `[10, 20, 30]`, instead of doing it all over from scratch.

For example, except for element `10` and `40`, the rest of the elements in the two steps are exactly the same.

With a queue, the first element can represent `10`, and when we are about the process the next round, we simply take away that first element and add the new element.

For finding the running median, I suggest looking the [two heaps pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmogG01IjYc)